# How can I get rid of the Warning: 'Clauses of .../2 are not together in the source file?

Tags: prolog

This is my code in the SWI:

```
schwester_von(a,b):-weiblich(c),mutter_von(c,a),mutter_von(c,b),a\==b.

bruder_von(a,b):-weiblich(c),mutter_von(c,a),mutter_von(c,b),a\==b.

grossvater_von(a,b):-maennlich(a),(vorfahr_von(a,c),
                                  (vater_von(c,b);mutter_von(c,b))).

vorfahr_von(a,b):-vater_von(a,b);mutter_von(a,b);((vater_von(a,c);mutter_von(a,c)),
                                                  vorfahr_von(c,b)).

einzelkind(a):-(vater_von(b,a);mutter_von(c,a)),not(bruder_von(a,d);
                                                    schwester_von(a,e)).

mutter_von(a,b):-weiblich(a).
vater_von(a,b):-maennlich(a).
schwester_von(a,b):-weiblich(a).
bruder_von(a,b):-maennlich(a).
grossvater_von(a,b):-maennlich(a).
grossmutter_von(a,b):-weiblich(a).

vater_von(stefan,barbara).
vater_von(stefan,annalena).
mutter_von(marianne,barbara).
mutter_von(marianne,annalena).
mutter_von(barbara,timo).
vater_von(christopher,timo).
mutter_von(annalena,ursula).
mutter_von(annalena,thomas).
vater_von(christian,ursula).
vater_von(christian,thomas).
mutter_von(ursula,uta).
vater_von(ralf,uta).
vater_von(thomas,sven).
mutter_von(sabrina,sven).

maennlich(stefan).
weiblich(barbara).
weiblich(annalena).
weiblich(marianne).
maennlich(timo).
maennlich(christopher).
weiblich(ursula).
maennlich(thomas).
maennlich(christian).
weiblich(uta).
maennlich(ralf).
maennlich(sven).
weiblich(sabrina).
```

After compiling following warnings occur:

```
    Warning: /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:16:
    Warning:    Clauses of schwester_von/2 are not together in the source-file
    Warning:    Earlier definition at /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:1
    Warning:    Current predicate: vater_von/2
    Warning:    Use :- discontiguous schwester_von/2. to suppress this message
    Warning: /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:17:
    Warning:    Clauses of bruder_von/2 are not together in the source-file
    Warning:    Earlier definition at /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:3
    Warning:    Current predicate: schwester_von/2
    Warning:    Use :- discontiguous bruder_von/2. to suppress this message
    Warning: /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:18:
    Warning:    Clauses of grossvater_von/2 are not together in the source-file
    Warning:    Earlier definition at /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:5
    Warning:    Current predicate: bruder_von/2
    Warning:    Use :- discontiguous grossvater_von/2. to suppress this message
    Warning: /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:21:
    Warning:    Clauses of vater_von/2 are not together in the source-file
    Warning:    Earlier definition at /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:15
    Warning:    Current predicate: grossmutter_von/2
    Warning:    Use :- discontiguous vater_von/2. to suppress this message
    Warning: /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:23:
    Warning:    Clauses of mutter_von/2 are not together in the source-file
    Warning:    Earlier definition at /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:14
    Warning:    Current predicate: vater_von/2
    Warning:    Use :- discontiguous mutter_von/2. to suppress this message
    Warning: /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:26:
    Warning:    Clauses of vater_von/2 are not together in the source-file
    Warning:    Earlier definition at /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:15
    Warning:    Current predicate: mutter_von/2
    Warning:    Use :- discontiguous vater_von/2. to suppress this message
    Warning: /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:27:
    Warning:    Clauses of mutter_von/2 are not together in the source-file
    Warning:    Earlier definition at /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:14
    Warning:    Current predicate: vater_von/2
    Warning:    Use :- discontiguous mutter_von/2. to suppress this message
    Warning: /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:29:
    Warning:    Clauses of vater_von/2 are not together in the source-file
    Warning:    Earlier definition at /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:15
    Warning:    Current predicate: mutter_von/2
    Warning:    Use :- discontiguous vater_von/2. to suppress this message
    Warning: /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:31:
    Warning:    Clauses of mutter_von/2 are not together in the source-file
    Warning:    Earlier definition at /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:14
    Warning:    Current predicate: vater_von/2
    Warning:    Use :- discontiguous mutter_von/2. to suppress this message
    Warning: /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:32:
    Warning:    Clauses of vater_von/2 are not together in the source-file
    Warning:    Earlier definition at /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:15
    Warning:    Current predicate: mutter_von/2
    Warning:    Use :- discontiguous vater_von/2. to suppress this message
    Warning: /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:34:
    Warning:    Clauses of mutter_von/2 are not together in the source-file
    Warning:    Earlier definition at /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:14
    Warning:    Current predicate: vater_von/2
    Warning:    Use :- discontiguous mutter_von/2. to suppress this message
    Warning: /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:40:
    Warning:    Clauses of maennlich/1 are not together in the source-file
    Warning:    Earlier definition at /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:36
    Warning:    Current predicate: weiblich/1
    Warning:    Use :- discontiguous maennlich/1. to suppress this message
    Warning: /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:42:
    Warning:    Clauses of weiblich/1 are not together in the source-file
    Warning:    Earlier definition at /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:37
    Warning:    Current predicate: maennlich/1
    Warning:    Use :- discontiguous weiblich/1. to suppress this message
    Warning: /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:43:
    Warning:    Clauses of maennlich/1 are not together in the source-file
    Warning:    Earlier definition at /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:36
    Warning:    Current predicate: weiblich/1
    Warning:    Use :- discontiguous maennlich/1. to suppress this message
    Warning: /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:45:
    Warning:    Clauses of weiblich/1 are not together in the source-file
    Warning:    Earlier definition at /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:37
    Warning:    Current predicate: maennlich/1
    Warning:    Use :- discontiguous weiblich/1. to suppress this message
    Warning: /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:46:
    Warning:    Clauses of maennlich/1 are not together in the source-file
    Warning:    Earlier definition at /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:36
    Warning:    Current predicate: weiblich/1
    Warning:    Use :- discontiguous maennlich/1. to suppress this message
    Warning: /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:48:
    Warning:    Clauses of weiblich/1 are not together in the source-file
    Warning:    Earlier definition at /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl:37
    Warning:    Current predicate: maennlich/1
    Warning:    Use :- discontiguous weiblich/1. to suppress this message
    % /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl compiled 0.00 sec, 38 clauses
    Warning: Cannot find anything to edit from "'Earlier definition at /Users/user1/Desktop/fakten.pl':1"
    XPCE Xt warning: locale not supported by Xlib, locale set to C
    ?-
```

I thought it's maybe because of the _ in the function names but there is also a warning for maennlich/1 and weiblich/1. I tried to give the function another name without _ but it's the same.

What can I do?

Comment: It would have been easier for you to just Google it: https://www.google.com/search?q=swi+prolog+clauses+are+not+together+in+the+source-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prolog Error: Clauses are not together in the source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66728693/prolog-error-clauses-are-not-together-in-the-source-file) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61160857/clauses-not-being-together-in-the-source-file-warning

Comment: I answered that too in my answer to your other question.